# Yii2. Ссылка в gridview для связанных моделей

Tags: php, yii2, ссылки, gridview, link

Здравствуйте. Как сделать ссылку в gridview я знаю, но возникла проблема с ссылкой для связанной модели.

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summary' => 'Показано {begin} - {end} из {totalCount} записей',
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'competition.title',

        [
            'attribute' => 'competition.title',
            'value' => function (ACompetition $data) {
                return Html::a(Html::encode($data->title), Url::to(['/' . $data->category->slug . '/' . $data->slug . '/' . $data->id]));
            },
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],
...
```

Само по себе `'competition.title'` работает, но вот со ссылкой не хочет, пишет такую ошибку:
`Argument 1 passed to yii\base\View::{closure}() must be an instance of common\models\ACompetition, instance of common\models\AOption given`. Понимаю, что первый аргумент должен принадлежать к модели ACompetition, но что-то у меня не получается.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: а что от чего наследуется? ACompetition от AOption?

Comment: @ЛешаМарченковский Обе от ActiveRecord. ACompetition hasMany AOption и AOption hasOne ACompetition

Comment: Как то странно у тебя всё. Для простоты кода во view.. сделай в моделе ACompetition функцию которая возвращает так как тебе нужно ссылку (код почти такой как есть у тебя внутри функции, просто вместо `$data` будешь обращаться к модели (`$this`) назовешь её например
`getCompetititonHref()` а потом во вьюшке уже к ней обратишься как столбцу `'competitionHref:html'` и все будет ок. В ссылке кстати не забудь отключить pjax, `['data-pjax'=>0]` иначе не будет корректно переходить. Такой подход нормальный имхо, но ломается сортировка (легко подправить).

Comment: @SultanovShamil Спасибо, ваш вариант работает. Если желаете, оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для простоты кода во view.. сделай в модели `ACompetition` функцию которая возвращает нужную ссылку (код останется почти таким же как у тебя внутри функции, просто вместо `$data` будешь обращаться к самой модели (`$this`) назовешь её например `getCompetititonHref()`, а потом во вьюшке к ней обратишься как столбцу `'competitionHref:html'` и все будет ок. В ссылке кстати не забудь отключить pjax, `['data-pjax'=>0]` иначе не будет корректно переходить. Такой подход нормальный имхо, но нужно добавить правило сортировки для поля.